# Linux From Scratch (7.9) Chapter 6.10 linking fails

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-from-scratch

[Here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/adjusting.html) is the step I'm on. Everything has gone fine up to this point, but after replacing the old linker with the new one and making the changes to the specs file, I get the following error when trying to compile dummy.c

```
 /tools/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/collect2 -plugin /tools/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/tools/libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cciBczi2.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/lib/crt1.o /usr/lib/crti.o /tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/crtbegin.o -L/tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0 -L/tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/lib /tmp/ccxbWIWi.o "" -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/crtn.o
/tools/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find : No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

After a lot of google searching, I've seen other posts about similar problems at the same stage, but all of those errors refer to specific files that are missing (usually crt*.o files), but this error is different and perplexing in that it doesn't actually list a file it can't find. I've made sure `ld` and the various links to it exist and do things when you invoke them. I've even cut and pasted the directory into a cd command and it does work (I was originally thrown off by the `/../../../../` in the path but it seems to work so okay). What file is missing or not being found by collect2?

Comment: ... Did you miss the empty pair of double quotes in the command line?

Comment: Can you get ld to output verbose?  Also ld usually prints the name of the missing file after that error, so it appears to be looking for a file called `:` might be worth checking if you've got an extra colon in there somewhere.

Comment: @GregHNZ No, it's looking for an empty filename because of this part: `... /tmp/ccxbWIWi.o "" -lgcc ...`

Comment: Since that part is generated by gcc/ld, I'm not sure where it's coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was an extra space in the command issued to compile the file.

The correct command is:
`cc dummy.c -v -Wl,--verbose &>dummy.log`

What I entered was:
`cc dummy.c -v -Wl, --verbose &>dummy.log`

That very small difference meant four hours of hair pulling. Thank you to everyone who offered help!